# Toilet tank over flowing

Tags: leak, toilet, overflow

My toilet tank will over flow after hours of unuse, and leaks from the handle. The fill valve has been replaced and the large flow of water will stop, you can hear and see it has stopped when the black floater rises after the toilet has been flushed. All seems well. However, hours later, if the toilet has not been used there will be water running down the front from the small hole at the handle. It is not the hole at the handle either, because the water turns off way before the level rises up that high. I do not understand why it is still slowly and silently filling, although the fill valve seems to be working properly.

Please help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fill mechanism is worn out and needs to be replaced. If the reservoir fills up to where the water leaks out from the handle then the overflow pipe is too long and needs to be cut down. The newer type fill valves are adjustable for the height of the water in the reservoir. I prefer the fluidmaster but you can choose you own brand.